# Extracting the nth digit of pi using Plouffe's formula?

Tags: pi

I have come upon the following formula to extract the nth digit of pi in base 10:
 $$\pi + 3 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n 2^n n!^2}{(2n)!}
$$
But this just seems to be a formula for pi. How can I use this formula to extract the nth digit of pi?

Comment: Calculate it out until the term is less than the signicance of the digt.

Comment: You use a spigot algorithm as per here.  http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Algorithms/SpigotForPi.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to find the $n$-th digit in base $d$ if you have a formula of the form

$$\sum_k \frac{\textbf{maybe large}}{\textbf{small} \times d^k},$$

like [BBP formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) for $d=16$. Just multiply the formula by $d^n$ and simplify the first $n$ summands as

$$\frac{(\textbf{maybe large} \times d^{n-k}) \text{ mod } \textbf{small}}{\textbf{small}}.$$

Then you need to sum up $n$ real numbers between $0$ and $1$ and several of the next terms (until the rest of series is small enough), see [an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm#Example) for $\ln 2$.

For BBP formula or $\ln 2$ example, the complexity of each step is $O(\log k)$, so the overall complexity is $O(n \log n)$. Your formula is used by [Plouffe](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0912/0912.0303.pdf) (difficult to read) with complexity $O(n^3 \log^3 n)$ -- but in any base. The version by [Goudon](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/nthdecimaldigit.pdf) is even more sophisticated, with complexity less than $O(n^2)$ in any base, but *Proposition 1* from there shows that the idea is as in the answer.